# Doubts related Shifting from Pure to Applied math

Tags: reference-request, career, applied-mathematics, advice

I am a second year (Pure) Math and (Theoretical) Physics undergraduate in India. I want to do a masters in Applied/Computational Science or Math, for which I have apply after next 7 months.

I have following questions:

1. Does having only theoretical knowledge of subjects, make me worthless candidate for applied stuff?
2. Since masters in many universities is not funded, are there any programmes or scholarships that can pay me at least for my tuition fee?
3. I have lots of electives left for next two semesters, what are some of the courses I should take( or you’ll take if you were me)?
4. With having no prior experience in applied stuff, what exactly should I write on my SOP when I apply?

Comment: Surely it's better to ask Applied faculty at your university than random strangers on the internet.

Comment: I wanted to ask them, but there’s no applied math faculty here in my university. It’s a small place and filled with people doing only theoretical stuff.

Comment: Theoretical physics involves applied math, by definition.

Comment: Ok. Then what is the difference between these two programmes ?